# 1 touch zoom issue for mobile site on opera

Tags: mobile, usability

I'm optimising my site for the web. For testing I've downloaded the Opera mini app for my iPhone and the Opera mobile desktop browser for my PC.

Often when you click or touch a link, rather than opening the link the browser zooms in first (you can then click the link). This behaviour is quite annoying and doesn't seem to happen on other sites.

Can I disable this functionality or alter my site so it stops happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opera only zooms in when you tap several links at once - in other words, when it's not possible to accurately tap one specific link. You can't stop that happening as far as I know, except for creating a mobile site that doesn't need to be zoomed in. Or, make sure the links are far enough apart so that users can accurately tap each one.